# exposing several servers with fully quallified domain names under same public ip using nat or port fowarding

Tags: virtualization, nat, xenserver

I am  network administrator.
I want to manage about 5 virtual machine servers under in a lan with each having a private ip in the range 10.10.10.0/29
Each server will have a hostname in the form server.domain.com
The servers will provide services to the internet through the **same public ip**.
I only have one public ip. so i plan to use Citrix xenserver to manage the vms and Clearos to work as a gateway
I have tried port fowarding and 1-1NAT on the gateway but i cant seem to foward packets based on the hostnames.
I actually expect thet when i type server1.domain.com on the internet it connects to that apache running in that vm and the same for the other vms.
I know i will need DNS but i dont know how to do my configure them?
I have already mapped all the damain names to the public ip.
Please help.

Comment: Get another external IP.

Answer (score 0):

In main machine add the host entry   127.0.0.1   dnsname-virtual-machine

Comment: you mean in the gateway or in the xenserver, since the packets will be fowarded between the gateway external interface and its lan interface then to the servers.

Comment: In the gateway .